# need help to build a query that takes the dynamic column name return by another query as record

Tags: oracle11g

I have 2 tables:

**Employee_tbl**

```
empid   empname     empsalary       emplocation
-----   -------     ---------       ------------

1       santhosh    15000           East godavari

2       Srinivas    25000           Westgodavari

3       sandeep     35000           Hyderabad

4       prathap     55000           Hyderabad

5       praveen     45000           West godavari
```

**configuration_tbl**

```
config_id   column_name
---------   -----------
1            empid      
2            empname        
3            empsalary  
4            emplocation
```

When I pass input as config_id  it should display the values from that column.

Ex: If I pass config_id then it should display all empname from employee_tbl.

Comment: Look at "execute immediate" statement.

Answer (score 0):

When there is only a limited number of columns I advice you to use a SQL with a `case` statement. Depending on whether you want to fold numbers into one text field or not, you may need two `case` columns. `Execute immediate` is possible but has additional overhead.